# Can't disable tabstop in WPF controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpf-controls

I have three `TextBoxes`, one `Button` and a `DataGrid` in my WPF Window

I want the user to be able to circle between textBoxes and the Button with `Tab`

The problem is is seems to stop on the dataGrid as well

I've tried setting the `IsTabStop` property to `False`, `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None"` and even setting the `Focusable` property to `False`, but it still focuses the datagird

To be more accurate, I tried to find out which item it is focusing with tab after textbox, and wrote this:

```
private void MyWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this).ToString());
        }
    }
```

And after going over textBoxes, it showed: `System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid Items.Count = 13`

How can I disable tabstop for my dataGrid?

Comment: Could you include your XAML code to test/debug with?

Comment: @KeithStein I uploaded all of my form's XAML here : https://github.com/MohammadHosseinS/There/blob/main/My%20XAML